# WPF. Feedback from binding object

Tags: binding

I have a TextBox in my view:

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10" AcceptsReturn="True" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Text="{Binding FileInputText}"></TextBox>
```

I want to TextBox could apply changes of its text to binding property FileInputText. How can I get it?
Thanks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default bindings work as a feed (binding mode is OneWay), to enable feedback you should set the binding mode to TwoWay (at least in Silverlight):

```
{Binding FileInputText, Mode=TwoWay}
```